# Error 403 when receiving http post from another server

Tags: php, laravel, http

I'm implementing a payment method in PHP Laravel 5.6, and i'm supposed to receive an online notification through POST to an url i provide. It is getting Error 403, my POSTS from within the APP work completely fine.

As this POST comes from outside with no csrf, i've added my route on VerifyCSRF exceptions. but still it keeps saying 403.

I'm using Laravel 5.6 on AWS Elastic beanstalk on a load balancer, on top of this i use cloudflare.

web.php route

```
Route::post('/tpv/notificationOK', 'TPVController@order_notificationOK');
```

VerifyCsrfToken.php

```
protected $except = [
        'tpv/notificationOK',
        'https://www.pcmaker.es/tpv/notificationOK'
    ];
```

I expect to receive a POST and execute order_notificationOK function on /tpv/notificationOK URL but instead i'm getting "Server returned HTTP response code: 403 for URL: /tpv/notificationOK"

----------EDIT-------------
Just in case it can help someone, Cloudflare was blocking the POST request causing into an error 403, i just had to whitelist the ip where the POST came from and it works fine.

Comment: Can you try with `"/tpv/notificationOK"` - should be working

Comment: @senty Yeah i tried with /tpv/notificationOK but i keep getting 403. Any ideas? This is driving me nuts

Comment: Are you sure it's csrf middleware causing this issue? Try commenting it out and test again.